# How do I inspect the Asp.Net request pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I measure request times on "the inside" of an Asp.Net application and compare it to timings on "the outside" of the app, I get different values -- 1000-5000ms strange overheads from time to time.

Maybe the requests are beeing queued up in front of IIS?

Or something strange is going on in an HttpModule?

The question: Is there a way to inspect the request pipeline for tracing exactly where the time is spent before the app is hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own module and register it on top to trace every request with more accuracy, but the measure will start once the IIS delegates the request to the ASP.NET ISAPI module. To get more accuracy you can go to IIS logs.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan said, you need enable tracing at the application level (web.config):

```
<!-- pageOutput enables trace output from the page itself -->
<system.web>
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" traceMode="SortByTime"/>
</system.web>
```

Or you can enable tracing at the page level. This can be done by setting the trace = "true" in Page directive.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="true" 
         Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

The application level tracing can be viewed from http://localhost/appname/trace.axd. This will show list of requests:

[image]

When you click on details of each page you can see how much time each event in the life cycle of the page took. This should help you to figure out where exactly your page is taking more than expected time.

[Image referenced from http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Built-in_Handlers.html]

Comment: Thanx - i've actually never used the trace.axd handler and it's a nice one! However as I need info about the pipeline before the app is hit, this doesn't help me.

Besides - the portal im working on have duplicate controlIds (not mine..) so trace doesnt work.

Comment: Nice, simple, down to the point. explanation on how to use tracing in ASP.NET. - That's how you condense 10-20 pages of Microsoft empty phrases to the core value. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on tracing in your web.config file. The line should say something like `<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" />`. The MSDN page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6915t83k.aspx).

Comment: I know this one -- but I need info about stuff before the app is hit. Thanx anyhows :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to also try out [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It allows you to see Modules in the request pipeline as well as a host of other information.