# How can I get the Initial Timestamp of Page Request when a page request is began in .NET Asp MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, httprequest

How can I get the Initial Timestamp of Page Request when a page request is began in .NET Asp MVC?  I'd like to compare that Timestamp to the beginning of an Action, and then again as the OnActionExecuted and see where in the pipeline my app is spending time before it begins responding with the "head" element, which it does concurrently while models and data requests are being processed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148384/how-do-i-inspect-the-asp-net-request-pipeline

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely useful, and I had used that before, but had since forgotten about it.  BUT, I'm looking to get timing from before .NET takes over, before HttpModules, and then timing through the modules, and then timing as the Action is being executed.  This should give me an idea if any HttpModules in the pipeline are causing issues.  I'm thinking an isapi filter approach -- after doing some more research.

Comment: in that case you question is related to the web server and not .net technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe to `Application_BeginRequest` in your Global.asax, you put the current timestamp into the HttpContext and then inside your `OnActionExecuted` or whatever you retrieve this timestamp from the HttpContext, calculate the new timestamp and make a substraction:

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Context.Items["timestamp"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

OnActionExecuted:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    DateTime initial = (DateTime)filterContext.HttpContext.Items["timestamp"];
    DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow;
    long totalMilliseconds = (long)(current - initial).TotalMilliseconds;
    ...
}
```